# How can I tell which data sources are being used in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

We have a bunch of SSRS (2008) reports deployed to our web portal.  We have edited some of the reports to use a shared data source different than the one with which it was originally deployed.

I am looking for a way to query the ReportServer database to show me which reports use which of these shared data sources. I found that you can use the XML data stored in Catalog.Content to show what data source is being used, but this appears to the data source with which the report was originally deployed.

Comment: I can't do a full answer, but you should be able to find it in ReportServerDB: there is an Item (?) table that contains all entities. And some link between a report and datasource item. Good hunting!

Comment: Thanks, gbn, but that's exactly what I can't find: the link between the catalog and datasource tables... there is no item table...

Comment: And, after close examination, I don't even think the shared data sources are in the datasource table.  The plot thickens.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, I got it.  Found this link which helped: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/581c7068-0abe-49f9-a1a5-93e94f472641/

I distilled that information to this query:

```
select
  Catalog.name,
  cat1.Name datasource
from
  Catalog
  join DataSource
    on Catalog.ItemID = DataSource.ItemID
  join Catalog cat1
    on DataSource.Link = cat1.ItemID
where
  Catalog.Type = 2
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: PERFECT. thanks for the followup "distilled" query. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: You the real MVP