# how to add a data source to SSRS - reporting services 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2014

For infomation as [Create, Modify, and Delete Shared Data Sources (SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155845.aspx)
but I want to get this done quickly, so when I have been requested to add a new data source to our reporting services:

[image]

This is the way I am currently doing it:
I look for another data source that I already have -  (example only - the real server name has been modified)

> http://myreportingserver/Reports/Pages/DataSource.aspx?ItemPath=%2fData+Sources%2fOEL_UK

there I have already another data source working fine, 
I get the information like the connection string, 
and the credentials (user name of the account running the report) and modify accordingly for my new data source.

[image]

then, for creating a new data source I go to the page below and press `new data source` adding the relevant data.

[image]

**Question**

Isn't there another simpler way of creating a data sources?

I was thinking something like from the `ReportingServices` database there must be some table with the datasource records, and all the information.
Just copying that info into another record, doing the appropriate changes - and I will have my new data source.

This question shows how to find data sources in the reporting services database

[How can I tell which data sources are being used in SSRS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/how-can-i-tell-which-data-sources-are-being-used-in-ssrs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio with SSDT-BI installed you can create new shared DataSources or copy/paste them. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155845(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: [Where can I find SSDT-BI for VS 2015 download?](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9588063-ssdt-bi-for-vs-2015)

Comment: where in the link you provided does it mention SSDT-BI?

Comment: if you have VS 2015 they should be installed. Or check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look into rs.exe (installed with SQL reporting services configuration). Is uses a vbscript syntax but it will allow you to do data source updates with command line/script.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx

Here is an example of the call to RS.EXE that you could put in a cmd or bat file.  If there is only one instance of SSRS and it is in the default instance then exclude the "_instancename" from the URL.

```
rs -i c:\temp\SSRS_EnableRemoteErrors.rss -s http://reportservername/ReportServer_instancename

pause
```

Here is the script it calls, in this example the script will enable remote errors on the SSRS instance.  There

```
Public Sub Main()
  Dim P As New [Property]()
  P.Name = "EnableRemoteErrors"
  P.Value = True
  Dim Properties(0) As [Property]
  Properties(0) = P
  Try
    rs.SetSystemProperties(Properties)
    Console.WriteLine("Remote errors enabled.")
  Catch SE As SoapException
    Console.WriteLine(SE.Detail.OuterXml)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: this is very interesting. I would like to see more examples though. Do you know of any?

Comment: I updated my answer with code samples.